# Wordpress Query Multiple Arguments Set Based on URL Variables

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have a custom post type and have created a handful of links in the breadcrumbs to allow sorting of the posts.  The sorting links set variables within the URL that are then pulled to determine the arguments for the query.

This is a jumbled mess.  But it functions as expected.  However, there has to be a better way to do this than this mess of code.  The only thing not working with this code is if NO variables are set in the URL it returns NO RESULTS instead of ALL RESULTS.

I am totally open if someone has a better way to sort posts by different meta keys/values on the fly/with links.

These are the variables its pulling from the URL:

```
$sortby = $_GET['sort'] or $sortby = 'price';
$direction = $_GET['dir'] or $direction = 'desc';
$automake = $_GET['make'] or $automake = '';
$autocat = $_GET['model'] or $autocat = '';
$searchkey = $_GET['s'] or $searchkey = '';
$autocondition = $_GET['cond'] or $autocondition = '';
```

And here is the jumbled up Query/Args code.

```
if ( $s !== '' ) {

$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'inventory',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'         => -1,
's'                      => $searchkey,
'order'                  => $direction,
'orderby'                => $orderby,
'meta_key'               => $sorting,
'meta_query'             => array(
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_sold',
        'value'     => 'No',
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
),

);
} elseif ( $autocondition !== '' ) {

$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'inventory',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'         => -1,
's'                      => $searchkey,
'order'                  => $direction,
'orderby'                => $orderby,
'meta_key'               => $sorting,
'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_sold',
        'value'     => 'No',
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_status',
        'value'     => $autocondition,
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
),

);
} elseif ( $automake AND $autocat !== '' ) {
$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'inventory',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'         => -1,
'order'                  => $direction,
'orderby'                => $orderby,
'meta_key'               => $sorting,
'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_sold',
        'value'     => 'No',
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_make',
        'value'     => $automake,
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_model',
        'value'     => $autocat,
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
),

);

} elseif ( $automake !== '' ) {
$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'inventory',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'         => -1,
'order'                  => $direction,
'orderby'                => $orderby,
'meta_key'               => $sorting,
'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_sold',
        'value'     => 'No',
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_make',
        'value'     => $automake,
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
),

);

} elseif ( $autocat !== '' ) {
$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'inventory',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'         => -1,
'order'                  => $direction,
'orderby'                => $orderby,
'meta_key'               => $sorting,
'meta_query'             => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_sold',
        'value'     => 'No',
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_model',
        'value'     => $autocat,
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
),

);

} else {

$args = array (
'post_type'              => 'inventory',
'post_status'            => 'publish',
'posts_per_page'         => -1,
'order'                  => $direction,
'orderby'                => $orderby,
'meta_key'               => $sorting,
'meta_query'             => array(
    array(
        'key'       => '_auto_sold',
        'value'     => 'No',
        'compare'   => '=',
        'type'      => 'CHAR',
    ),
),

);
}

// The Query
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

In the else part use

```
$args = array ('post_type' =>'inventory', 'post_status' => 'publish','posts_per_page' => -1 );
```

This would work